# Microk8s - pod eviction

Tags: microk8s

I am trying to use the "pod eviction" functionality of microk8s, but so far with no success.

This is my setup:

I have a microk8s cluster formed of 3 nodes.

```
ubuntu@microk8snode1demo:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
microk8snode3demo   Ready    <none>   45h   v1.26.6
microk8snode2demo   Ready    <none>   45h   v1.26.6
microk8snode1demo   Ready    <none>   45h   v1.26.6
```

I have deployed a daemonset.

```
ubuntu@microk8snode1demo:~$ kubectl get pods | grep dg
my-daemonset-dg-qj74c   1/1     Running   0               19m
my-daemonset-dg-ntnfc   1/1     Running   0               19m
my-daemonset-dg-z2z9v   1/1     Running   1 (63s ago)     19m
```

I have added these parameters in ***/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-apiserver***

```
--default-not-ready-toleration-seconds=60
--default-unreachable-toleration-seconds=60
--enable-admission-plugins="DefaultTolerationSeconds
```

and in **/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-controller-manager**

```
--pod-eviction-timeout=1m
```

This has been done on all 3 nodes of the cluster. After I added those parameters to those 2 file I have restared the daemon-kubelite service.

```
systemctl restart snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite
```

After that I have closed microk8s on one node.

```
ubuntu@microk8snode1demo:~$ sudo microk8s stop
Stopped.
```

Now I go to another node.

```
ubuntu@microk8snode3demo:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
microk8snode1demo   NotReady   <none>   46h   v1.26.6
microk8snode3demo   Ready      <none>   46h   v1.26.6
microk8snode2demo   Ready      <none>   45h   v1.26.6
ubuntu@microk8snode3demo:~$ 
ubuntu@microk8snode3demo:~$ 

ubuntu@microk8snode3demo:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide | grep dg
my-daemonset-dg-qj74c   1/1     Running   0               29m   192.168.69.87    microk8snode3demo   <none>           <none>
my-daemonset-dg-ntnfc   1/1     Running   0               29m   192.168.68.73    microk8snode2demo   <none>           <none>
my-daemonset-dg-z2z9v   1/1     Running   1 (11m ago)     29m   192.168.69.214   microk8snode1demo   <none>           <none>
```

We can see that microk8snode1demo is "NotReady" but the pod "my-daemonset-dg-z2z9v"  is "Running".
In theory this pod should have been evicted but it is not. Is there somethong I am doing wrong, or shall I add/delete/modify another parameter?